# vim filetype plugin conflict with session

Tags: session, vim

### Problem

When I restore from a session, It'll be impossible for to load my filetype plugin.

For example, I have an arduino filetype plugin of *~/.vim/ftplugin/arduino.vim*, and the content is like this.

```
SyntasticToggleMode
call feedkeys("\<CR>")
nnoremap <leader>s :w<cr>:ArduinoVerify<cr>
nnoremap M :ArduinoUpload<cr>
```

I create an arduino file named test.ino to do some coding.
Every thing seems pretty smooth.
The filetype plugin is loaded properly.

Then I close vim with the following commands.

- `:mksession!`
- `:wviminfo viminfo`
- `:qa`

Now there is a session file named Session.vim.
Then I open vim again, and it automatically load the session because I have something like this in my *.vimrc*.

```
filetype indent plugin on 
if filereadable("Session.vim")
    source Session.vim          
endif         
if filereadable("viminfo")
    rviminfo viminfo
endif
```

Now something went wrong, the key mapping in my arduino filetype plugin is not working.
Also it prints some error message like this.

`Error detected while processing /home/lotp/.vim/ftplugin/arduino.vim:
line    1:
E492: Not an editor command: SyntasticToggleMode"sketch_dec06a.ino" "sketch_dec06a.ino" 12L, 150C
E492: Not an editor command: SyntasticToggleMode`

Indeed`SyntasticToggleMode` is a valid vim command belonging to a vim plugin named syntastic.

### Question

Is there a solution to solve this problem?
By this I mean using the session and filetype plugin feather simultaneously.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I work around this problem by using an vim plugin.

That's somekind of improved version of the built in vim session system

It's called [vim-session](https://github.com/xolox/vim-session)

Answer (score 1):

A partial answer:

The plugins are not loaded directly in `.vimrc` if you use a plugin manager. Their paths are just appended to `'runtimepath'`, and they are sourced later in the initialisation process.

You can try to add (i.e. in `.vimrc`) your own custom path to `runtimepath`, AFTER the end of the plugin initialisation. (i.e., for Vundle, after this line: `call vundle#end()`) Then add a vim file in `your_custom_path/plugin` where you put your code to source the session file.

I didn't check all the infos I gave, so sorry for mistakes, but hope it gives you some ideas.

See `:h startup`, `:h 'runtimepath'`