# make session settings saving function play nice with ultisnips

Tags: macos, session, vim

I'm using the following function from [go away and come back script](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Go_away_and_come_back) to save and load sessions when I quit and start `vim`. It basically saves all my settings, files in buffers etc in `session.vim` file in the directory where I opened vim.

```
function! MakeSession()
  let b:sessiondir = $HOME . "/.vim/sessions" . getcwd()
  if (filewritable(b:sessiondir) != 2)
    exe 'silent !mkdir -p ' b:sessiondir
    redraw!
  endif
  let b:filename = b:sessiondir . '/session.vim'
  exe "mksession! " . b:filename
endfunction

function! LoadSession()
  let b:sessiondir = $HOME . "/.vim/sessions" . getcwd()
  let b:sessionfile = b:sessiondir . "/session.vim"
  if (filereadable(b:sessionfile))
    exe 'source ' b:sessionfile
  else
    echo "No session loaded."
  endif
endfunction
au VimEnter * nested :call LoadSession()
au VimLeave * :call MakeSession()
```

Recently I added [`ultisnips`](https://github.com/SirVer/ultisnips) plugin.

```
"Snippet engine
Plugin 'SirVer/ultisnips'
"Snippets are separated from the engine. Add this if you want them:
Plugin 'honza/vim-snippets'
```

Now when `session.vim` is created and I open vim after that, I get this error trace. This happens in `insert` mode when I try to edit also.

> ".vim/vimrc" 287L, 9566C
>   Error detected while processing /Users/sudobangbang/.vim/bundle/ultisnips/autoload/UltiSnips.vim:
>   line   15:
>   Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> Error detected while processing /Users/sudobangbang/.vim/bundle/ultisnips/autoload/UltiSnips.vim:
>   line   15:
>     File "", line 1, in 
>   Press ENTER or type command to continue
>   Error detected while processing /Users/sudobangbang/.vim/bundle/ultisnips/autoload/UltiSnips.vim:
>   line   15:
>   ImportError: No module named UltiSnips
>
> Error detected while processing function UltiSnips#FileTypeChanged:
>   line    1:
>   Traceback (most recent call last):
>   Error detected while processing function UltiSnips#FileTypeChanged:
>   line    1:
>   NameError: name 'UltiSnips_Manager' is not defined
>
> Error detected while processing function UltiSnips#TrackChange:
>   line    1:
>   Traceback (most recent call last):

If I remove functions for loading sessions, It works fine. Also here are all the lines in `session.vim` which has ultisnips in it.

```
inoremap <silent> <C-Tab> ^V^R=UltiSnips#ListSnippets()^V^M
xnoremap <silent> ^V   :call UltiSnips#SaveLastVisualSelection()^V^Mgvs
snoremap <silent> ^V   ^V^[:call UltiSnips#ExpandSnippet()^V^M
snoremap <silent> <C-Tab> ^V^[:call UltiSnips#ListSnippets()^V^M


set runtimepath=~/.vim,~/.vim/bundle/Vundle.vim,~/.vim/bundle/syntastic,~/.vim/bundle/nerdtree,~/.vim/bundle/vim-colorschemes,~/.vim/bundle/YouCompleteMe,~/.vim/bundle/supertab,~/.vim/bundle/ultisnips    ,~/.vim/bundle/vim-snippets,~/.vim/bundle/ctrlp.vim,~/.vim/bundle/vim-go,~/.vim/bundle/vim-commentary,~/.vim/bundle/vim-surround,~/.vim/bundle/vim-fugitive,~/.vim/bundle/vim-unimpaired,~/.vim/bundle/v    im-repeat,~/.vim/bundle/vim-airline,~/.vim/bundle/vim-airline-themes,~/.vim/bundle/gundo.vim,~/.vim/bundle/emmet-vim,~/.vim/bundle/html5.vim,~/.vim/bundle/vim-css-color,~/.vim/bundle/python-mode,~/.vi    m/bundle/vim-flake8,~/.vim/bundle/vim-ruby,~/.vim/bundle/vim-endwise,~/.vim/bundle/vim-rails,~/.vim/bundle/vim-bundler,~/.vim/bundle/vim-rake,~/.vim/bundle/vim-ruby-refactoring,~/.vim/bundle/apidock.v    im,~/.vim/bundle/blockle.vim,~/.vim/bundle/vim-rspec,~/.vim/bundle/javascript-libraries-syntax.vim,~/.vim/bundle/tern_for_vim,~/.vim/bundle/vim-javascript,/usr/local/share/vim/vimfiles,/usr/local/shar    e/vim/vim74,/usr/local/share/vim/vimfil
```

How can I change my session function so that vim loads `ultisnips` correctly?

```
vim --version
```

> VIM - Vi IMproved 7.4 (2013 Aug 10, compiled Jun  4 2016 11:48:12)
>   MacOS X (unix) version
>   Included patches: 1-1864
>   Compiled by Homebrew

Comment: Not sure this would be enough, but try to load sessions after your plugins have been initialized.  Depending on your plugin manager, doing this may be easy (as in, just mode the call to `LoadSession()` to the end of your vimrc), hard, or impossible. :)

Comment: Good thinking I'll give it a try

Comment: I got similar errors in Windows GVim when just loading the session via the command line with `gvim -S <session-file>`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I made a fix but while sacrificing some functionality.

I removed this line from session loading

```
au VimEnter * nested :call LoadSession()
```

and made a key mapping to manually load the session

```
map <leader>l :call LoadSession()<CR>
```

Hypothesis in @Sato Katsura's comment seem to be valid.
Now I'm researching if I can go to automated part with this getting this function called when all plugins are loaded.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this using Tim Pope's [obsession.vim](https://github.com/tpope/vim-obsession) plugin, then the `Session.vim` file that gets created can be loaded in the usual way either through `-S Session.vim` or `source Session.vim` and UltiSnips works again.

In the [readme](https://github.com/tpope/vim-obsession#obsessionvim) this line might explain the difference:

> - [When saving the session] Don't capture options and maps. Options are sometimes mutilated and maps just interfere with updating plugins.

Here's somewhat of an explanation:

From the [vim-session plugin README](https://github.com/xolox/vim-session#compatibility-with-other-plug-ins)

> Vim's :mksession command isn't really compatible with plug-ins that create buffers with generated content and because of this the vim-session plug-in includes specific workarounds for a couple of popular plug-ins:

I was pointed at the vim-session plugin by this more general [SO question on plugin issues with sessions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34217206/327074).